# run function at timer

Tags: function, actionscript, timer

I want to run a `function<display()>` every 3 seconds.
when I run the function I get the following error:

```
RangeError: Error #1125: The index 7 is out of range 4.
    at views::twoHomeView/onTimer()[C:\Users\Kinect\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\yattah\src\views\twoHomeView.mxml:26]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

My code is:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
        import flash.utils.Timer;

        private var timer:Timer;

        public function Main():void {
            timer = new Timer(1000, 3);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
            timer.start();
        }

        var kaisu:int =0; 

        private function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void {
            for(var i:int;i<5;i++){
                display(n[kaisu]);
                kaisu += kaisu+1;
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your `n` array has only 4 elements and you're trying to access the element number 7.

The cause of your problem is here:

```
        for(var i:int;i<5;i++){
            display(n[kaisu]);
            kaisu += kaisu+1; //<-- here your values will be 0,1,3,7..
        }
```

I'm sure it does not increment as you'd want it to:

Try this:

```
        for(var i:int=0;i<5;i++){
            display(n[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks your advice. try your code and result is No error. but this case can't run function<display> every 3 second

Answer (score 0):

The problem ins your var i isnt setting to 0.

Comment: when you declare an int var it is set to 0 by default